# Edit table or map metadata programmatically via API in CartoDB

Tags: carto, api, metadata

I'm trying to automate the creation of datasets and maps with CartoDB.
Now I would like to add the metadata information (source, attribution, description, etc).

Is it possibile? 
I don't find this in the documentation (but maybe I miss something...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're looking for doesn't exist yet. CartoDB does not provide any Datasets/Visualizations API to interact programatically with your Datasets (create, delete, change privacy, edit metadata) or Maps inside the CartoDB application.

As you might now already you can use the SQL API to create tables and make them appear in your CartoDB app by "CartoDBFying" them afterwards. This also allows most of the functionality you might want to use in your tables, such as renaming, but it does not allow to interact totally with your Datasets in terms of metadata or privacy.

Comment: Thank you. Have you planned a development of this feature?